# Rotation animation rotates twice at the beginning

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just noticed that rotation animation rotates twice as much as it should after hot restart. After that it runs fine but just because that first glitch the button is up side down. I've got this button which should rotates 180 degree on each press.

```
  AnimationController _animationController;
  bool pressed = false;
  Animation<double> _animation;

 @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }


_animation =
    Tween<double>(begin: !pressed ? 0 : 0.5, end: !pressed ? 0.5 : 1)
        .animate(_animationController);

  SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size(50, 50),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.forward(from: 0);
                setState(() {
                  pressed = !pressed;
                });
              },
              splashColor: Colors.black12,
              child: RotationTransition(
                turns: _animation,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.filter_list,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do it with `AnimationBuilder`?

Comment: Actually I did but with exactly same result...

Comment: Do you need always clockwise rotation on isPressed toggle? I can show in answer where is main error of this approach, but finally I think you need some solution, so describe behavior you want to see - so I can help with

Comment: No... I don’t really care about rotation direction but the position of the icon

Comment: @SergeySalnikov Behaviour is I guess quite obvious from the question.. When `pressed` variable is false than the icon should be in normal position, when the `pressed` is true then the icon should be at 180 degree. As you can see from the video the first press rotates the icon 360 degree. If you slow down the animation it basically rotates it 180 degree but starts from wrong position

Comment: do you want to see error in your approach step by step?

Comment: @SergeySalnikov yes you can include reason why it didn't work in your answer

Comment: i've added short steps what is going on in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [choosing an approach  in Animation introduction](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations)

In your case I would prefer [TweenAnimationBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html)

```
  /// content of State of statefull widget
  bool pressed = false;
  Tween<double> _tween = Tween<double>(begin: null, end: 0.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          tween: _tween,
          builder: (context, turns, child) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _tween = Tween<double>(end: pressed ? 0 : 0.5);
                pressed = !pressed;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: turns * pi * 2, /// need to import 'dart:math';
                child: Text('$pressed'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

P.S. A little word about problem in your approach.

You rely on rebuilding & animationController in same time but they independent of each other

1. inits with pressed= false and tween 0 -> 0.5
2. when tapped  animation starts animating from 0 -> 0.5
3. setState pressed=true and  widgets rebuilded with new tween 0.5 -> 1, animationController still not completed &  animating this time to new values 0.5 -> 1 - you can see this step

Comment: where do you initialise `turns` variable?

Comment: it's not initialized it part of `builder: (_, turns, child)` - finaly it's a AnimationController value modified by Tweens you passed to TweenAnimationBuilder

Comment: ah... sorry.. got it.. hold on